# Dynamic nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have dynamic divs on a page which would have anassigned class from a bunch of values. For example:

```
<div class='class1'><span class='spn1'>test</span></div>
<div class='class2'><span class='spn2'>test another</span></div>
<div class='class2'><span class='spn3'>test1</span></div>
<div class='class3'><span class='spn4'>test123</span></div>
<div class='class1'><span class='spn221'>test</span></div>
```

The class could have any random number appended to it.

Now in my javascript, I am trying to build a dynamic JSON object based on the class of the div and the structure I want is:

```
{
    class1: {
        spn1: 'test',
        spn221: 'test'
    },
    class2: {
        spn2: 'test another',
        spn3: 'test123'
    },
    class3: {
        spn4: 'test223'
    }
}
```

I am able to achieve this in a flat array structure but I want it in the JSON format as I will execute an ajax call based in the classes of div in other function. The flat array I am getting is as(which I don't want)

```
[{class:class1,span:spn1,text:test},{class:class1,span:spn221,text:test},...]
```

**Link to fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/8v0uove3/

Comment: How to you get the "flat array" ? Seems like turning the array into the object would be easy enough (with, eg. _.reduce), is that impossible ?

Comment: @phtrivier by _reduce, can I append objects as I want? Can you give a dummy example?

Comment: Can you create a FIDDLE for the problem ?

Comment: @Mayank added fiddle link

Comment: nvm ... misunderstood

Comment: @Saksham I have written the complete function (Pure JavaScript) below. Have a look. The output has been displayed in the browser console. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @krishnaxv I had already figured this out before anyone posted a solution.

Comment: @Saksham Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla JS way of doing it:

```
// pick up the elements
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="class"]');

// use reduce with an initial object
var obj = [].slice.call(divs).reduce(function (p, c) {
  var child = c.firstChild;
  var key = c.getAttribute('class');

  // if the class key doesn't exist in the initial object add it
  if (!p[key]) p[key] = {};

  // add the new span properties to the object
  p[key][child.getAttribute('class')] = child.textContent;
  return p;
}, {});
```

Output

```
{
  "class1": {
    "spn1": "test",
    "spn221": "test"
  },
  "class2": {
    "spn2": "test another",
    "spn3": "test1"
  },
  "class3": {
    "spn4": "test123"
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y2e2frL1/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete `function`. This is a `Pure JavaScript` solution. Please have a look at the code below.

> **Function**
>
> ```
> function convertHtmlToJson() {
>   var
>     output = {},
>     divRef = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="class"]'),
>     divElem = undefined;
>
>   for (var i = 0; i < divRef.length; i++) {
>     divElem = divRef[i].getAttribute('class');
>
>     // Check if key exists or not
>     if (!output[divElem]) {  // output[divElem] === undefined
>       output[divElem] = {}
>     }
>
>     // Get child element
>     childRef = divRef[i].firstElementChild || divRef.firstChild;
>
>     var className = document.getElementsByClassName(childRef.getAttribute('class'));
>     for (var j = 0; j < className.length; j++) {
>       output[divElem][className[j].getAttribute('class')] = className[j].textContent;
>     }
>   }
>   return output;
> }
> ```
>
> **Function call**
>
> ```
> // Final JSON
> var finalJson = convertHtmlToJson();
>
> // Desired JSON output
> console.log(JSON.stringify(finalJson));
> ```

You can look at the Browser Console for the desired `JSON` output.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get a solution, is this your desired result? (Take a look at the console output)

```js
var obj = {};
$('div').each(function() {
  // Get children
  var children = $(this).children();
  // Get current class
  var current = $(this).attr('class');
  // Check if current class already exists in the class object
  // If not create an empty object
  if (typeof obj[current] === 'undefined') {
    obj[current] = {};
  }
  // Iterate over div's children
  $(children).each(function() {
    // Get class value of child element
    var childCls = $(this).attr('class');
    // Set the value for child object
    obj[current][childCls] = $(this).text();
  })
});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='class1'><span class='spn1'>test</span>  <span class='spn3'>test</span> 
</div>
<div class='class2'><span class='spn2'>test another</span>
</div>
<div class='class2'><span class='spn3'>test1</span>
</div>
<div class='class3'><span class='spn4'>test123</span>
</div>
<div class='class1'><span class='spn221'>test</span>
</div>
```